# Always running webserver on android

Tags: android, service, foreground, nanohttpd

I want to switch on the display (and do other stuff like showing some information) of my android tablet via an external command. My solution was to start a webserver on the tablet, open a webpage and then the display should be switched on.

This works if I start the app but after a while the webserver does not respond anymore. I can see in my wifi router that the wifi connection is still OK. If I close and start the app again it works again for a while. It looks like my service is going to be killed by android.

I started the server as a service from the MainActivity (onCreate) with `startService(new Intent(this, ServerService.class));`.

ServerService extends Service. In onCreate I did the following:

```
PowerManager mgr = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyWakeLock");
wakeLock.acquire();

WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiManager.WifiLock lock = wifiManager.createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL, "WifiLockTag");
lock.acquire();
```

and in onStartCommand I set the service to foreground, start the server and return `START_STICKY`:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);


Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setContentTitle("Test")
            .setContentText("Testing...")
            .setOngoing(true)

            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

startForeground(mNotificationId, notification);

webServer = new WebServer(this);
webServer.start();
```

WebServer extends NanoHTTPD and there I implemented `serve( IHTTPSession session )`.

The ServerService is in the AndroidManifest:

```
 <service
     android:name=".ServerService"
     android:enabled="true" />
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: If this is on Android 6.0+, welcome to Doze mode.

Comment: No, the device has Android 4.1.

Comment: create background service that always run and create nanohttpd server in that service.
https://github.com/pathikdevani/Flysync/blob/master/flysync-android/flysync/src/main/java/com/pathik/service/MyService.java

Comment: @pathikdevani Don't you need to hold a wait lock somewhere?